# How to add field in MySQL result?

Tags: php, mysql

I want add one filed to result of queries in MySQL.
this tables is my database tables :

**tbl_user**

```
id_user | username | password
-----------------------------     
  1     |  Pooria    | 123456
  2     |  mary      | 123456
  3     |  july      | 123456
  4     |  Ali       | 123456
  5     |  shahla    | 123456
```

**tbl_category**

```
id_category | name
--------------------
1           | BMW
2           | Toyota
3           | Benz
```

**tbl_content**

```
id_content | message    | ContentLike
--------------------------------------
1          |   Best Car |    2
2          |   Best Car |    3
3          |   Best Car |    4
4          |   Best Car |    1
5          |   Best Car |    1
```

**tbl_user_category_content**

```
id | id_user | id_category | id_content
----------------------------------------
1  |  2      |   2         | 4
1  |  3      |   3         | 3
1  |  4      |   3         | 5
1  |  5      |   1         | 2
```

**tbl_user_like**

```
id_user_like | id_user | id_content
-------------------------------------     
1            |     2   |    5
1            |     2   |    3
1            |     5   |    1
1            |     4   |    2
1            |     4   |    2
```

My Query in Mysql :

```
SELECT tbl_content.id_content ,tbl_content.message,tbl_content.ContentLike,tbl_category.name,tbl_user.username
        FROM tbl_user_category_content
        INNER JOIN tbl_user ON
        tbl_user_category_content.id_user = tbl_user.id_user 
        INNER JOIN tbl_cat ON
        tbl_user_category_content.id_category = tbl_cat.id_category
        INNER JOIN tbl_post ON
        tbl_user_category_content.id_content = tbl_content.id_content
```

**and Result**

```
id_content | message  | ContentLike | username 
----------------------------------------------
    1      | Best Car | 2           | Pooria
    2      | Best Car | 4           | mary
    3      | Best Car | 3           | july
    4      | Best Car | 5           | Ali
    5      | Best Car | 4           | shahla
```

I expect Result :

I want insert a id_user  and view Result:

example :   insert id_user : 2 (mary)

```
id_content | message       | ContentLike | username    | Like_User 
-------------------------------------------------------------------     
1          | hello world1  | 4           |  Pooria     |  
2          | hello world2  | 2           | mary        |
3          | hello world3  | 2           | july        | Yes
4          | hello world4  | 2           | Ali         |
5          | hello world5  | 2           | shahla      | Yes
```

add result Like_User

important:I want all entries in the database with the person who likes to show a distinct field. thanks you for help me <3

Comment: what does this like_user column suppose to show????

Comment: @ManojSalvi, such as LINE application. for example when click by user on Like button, like button light for every day for this user. can you help me ?

Comment: you need query right??

Comment: @darshandave, yeah i need true query

Comment: You need a WHERE clause. Otherwise you will get all the results. WHERE tbl_user.id_user = 2

Comment: @PuyaSarmidani, such as LINE application. for example when click by user on Like button, like button light for every day for this user. can you help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this in the select columns :

```
case when tbl_user.id_user=tbl_user_like.id_user then 'Yes' else 'No' end as Like_User
```

So it would be something like this

```
SELECT tbl_content.id_content ,tbl_content.message,tbl_content.ContentLike,tbl_category.name,tbl_user.username, case when tbl_user.id_user=tbl_user_like.id_user then 'Yes' else 'No' end as Like_User
    FROM tbl_user_category_content
    INNER JOIN tbl_user ON
    tbl_user_category_content.id_user = tbl_user.id_user 
    INNER JOIN tbl_cat ON
    tbl_user_category_content.id_category = tbl_cat.id_category
    INNER JOIN tbl_post ON
    tbl_user_category_content.id_content = tbl_content.id_content
```

I have not test it. Try it out and maybe you should change the column names in the case

Comment: your name is like Iranian Names, can you speak persian?

Comment: But does this help you further? I don't have the same database build up so i wont be able to test it first. But what i understand is that you want to create a non existing column that is able to show if someone liked User or not.

Comment: @ tnx my dear friend, i am speak persian too. can you send me Line or Telegram account for help me? i really need this hel. tnx <3

Answer (score 0):

### Try This Query

```
    SELECT distinct tbl_content.id_content ,tbl_content.message,tbl_content.ContentLike,tbl_category.name,tbl_user.username,tbl_user_category_content.category
    FROM tbl_user_category_content
    INNER JOIN tbl_user,tbl_cat,tbl_post ON
    tbl_user_category_content.id_user = tbl_user.id_user 
    tbl_user_category_content.id_category = tbl_cat.id_category
    tbl_user_category_content.id_content = tbl_content.id_content
    WHERE tbl_user.id_user='$user_id'
```

Comment: select column as per your need ok

Comment: tnx. but the code that you've just shows what the user has like, we also want to see content that has not Likes

Comment: such as LINE application. for example when click by user on Like button, like button light for every day for this user. can you help me ?

Comment: ok add one more column in user table such as like/dislike and datatype is boolean or in mysql enum if value is 1 that it will display red light and if its 0 then it show white color got it.